# Issue with charmed kubeflow

Tags: kubeflow, microk8s, juju

I am quite new to juju and started to install charmed kubeflow as shown in below link
https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/get-started-with-charmed-kubeflow

As part of " Configure the Charmed Kubeflow components" I have configured below commands

```
juju config dex-auth public-url=http://10.64.140.43.nip.io
juju config oidc-gatekeeper public-url=http://10.64.140.43.nip.io
```

Looks like 10.64.140.43 ipaddress is the Kubeflow dashboard. But I dont see it configured anywhere in my system. When I tried to ping it from another machine it fails. How can I access the kubeflow page ?

Also I am using a single VM running 22.04 with 20GB of ram and 8vCPUs. Once I installed kubeflow I can see that CPU usage is around 90% and Ram usage is almost 100%. What is the minimum CPU requirement for running charmed kubeflow ?

```
    Tasks: 568 total,   3 running, 565 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 46.3 us, 20.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 31.1 id,  0.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.6 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  20007.9 total,    412.6 free,   5405.4 used,  14189.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2045.5 free,      2.5 used.  14227.7 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                       
    672 root      20   0 2305992 134716  42264 S 100.0   0.7  10:12.49 containerd                                                    
   2546 ipi       20   0  325580  10032   7308 R 100.0   0.0  18:59.08 gvfs-udisks2-vo                                               
 236892 root      20   0   18172  14208   6516 R  85.0   0.1   0:00.17 python3                                                       
    675 root      20   0 2393496 429028  18152 S  65.0   2.1   9:34.72 k8s-dqlite                                                    
   1543 root      20   0 2219152   1.3g 101568 S  60.0   6.4  14:03.99 kubelite                                                      
  20814 root      20   0 1005656 280556  91924 S  20.0   1.4   9:01.81 jujud                                                         
 236890 ipi       20   0   22640   4804   3524 R  20.0   0.0   0:00.08 top                                                           
  20470 root      20   0 2240592 455236  53752 S  15.0   2.2   5:26.83 mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum requirements are: at least 4 cores, 32GB RAM and 50GB of disk space available.

If you look for something more lightweight, there is also Charmed MLFlow available.